# Specific keys not working after the latest update on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, 22.04, keyboard-layout, keys

I'm having a particularly nasty keyboard issue where keys A, S and L don't work. I have a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 laptop and it was working fine yesterday.
I have a Windows VM and Windows is installed. In Windows or the fullscreen mode VM the keys work perfectly. As soon as I interact with my Kubuntu interface, they stop working even in the VM.

The keys work correctly on the login screen. They also work if I press Shift + the letter and this inputs the correct letter in uppercase.

I've tried:

- All keyboard models in settings -> this sometimes causes a letter to work once and then, when i try to use it again, it doesn't work anymore.
- Changing language distribution back and forth.
- Checked sticky keys, they were disabled: I enabled and disabled them again, no luck.
- External keyboard, does exactly the same.
- Updated X11 input drivers and restarted.
- Tried `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and changing layouts and languages. No luck.
- Tried rebooting the PC into windows, checking that the keyboard works and coming back to Ubuntu. No luck.

Comment: Have you maybe tried to use some kind of custom key config before this issue started? Have you booted from the Live Media and used the try option to see if the problem is there?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone having this issue, I solved it by deleting files in the .config folder that involved keyboard layout.

Restarted the PC, and they got reconfigured. It works correctly now.

Thanks everyone for your help ☺️