# Keyboard and mouse problems

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout

System is:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04.2
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 5.19.0-50-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11

I have been having problems with my laptop's keyboard, and more lately the mouse as well, for some time. On doing a search of StackExchange I came across

[Specific keys not working after the latest update on Kubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461773/specific-keys-not-working-after-the-latest-update-on-kubuntu-22-04/1480144?noredirect=1#comment2591771_1480144)

from user @Dani Williams who seemed to have had the same problems as I am currently having and who eventually provided her own answer by stating

> To anyone having this issue, I solved it by deleting files in the .config folder that involved keyboard layout.

Does anyone have an idea as to specifically what files in `.config` user @Dani Williams was referring?

Comment: I would guess the files in `~/.config/kdedefaults`.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: Thank you for a swift response. I've just had a look inside all of the files in that folder. None of them mentions a keyboard in any way. I guess that I need to keep on searching. Thanks again.